# Convert value into two decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help to convert value of the column "Pct_To_Total" into

```
John,     0,36  
Sophia,   0,29  
Stella,   0,18  
Jennifer, 0,11
```

Two decimal is needed only and the second decimal needed to be converted into higher value if the third decimal is bigger than value 4.

[image: Orginal value]

```
declare @T table  
(  
  Name varchar(50),  
  Sales decimal  
)  

insert into @T values  
('John',     '50'),  
('Sophia',   '40'),
('Stella',   '25'),  
('Jennifer', '15'), 
('Greg',     '10')  

SELECT a1.Name, a1.Sales, (a1.Sales /(SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM @T Total_Sales) ) AS Pct_To_Total
FROM @T a1, @T a2 
WHERE a1.Sales <= a2.sales or (a1.Sales=a2.Sales and a1.Name = a2.Name) 
GROUP BY a1.Name, a1.Sales
ORDER BY a1.Sales DESC, a1.Name DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT round (cast(0.35714285 AS DECIMAL(10,2)),2);
```

this gives `0.36` your excepted result.

I tried the following query it works fine.

```
SELECT a1.Name, a1.Sales, round(cast((a1.Sales /(SELECT SUM(Sales) FROM @T Total_Sales)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)),2) AS Pct_To_Total
FROM @T a1, @T a2 
WHERE a1.Sales <= a2.sales or (a1.Sales=a2.Sales and a1.Name = a2.Name) 
GROUP BY a1.Name, a1.Sales
ORDER BY a1.Sales DESC, a1.Name DESC;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Str()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)**

```
STR(123.468, 8, 2)
```

### Result

```
123.47
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `round` function

-> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

There are some options to do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROUND(0.36, 2)   = 0.36
SELECT ROUND(0.364, 2)  = 0.36
SELECT ROUND(0.365, 2)  = 0.37
```